# How to install Generatedata.com on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I want to install Generatedata.com on WAMP Server, I extracted generatedata's .zip file in `www` folder full path `C:\wamp\www\generatedata-3.2.0` which is available on BenKeen's Github.

But I am not able access it through http request which is resulting in "Network Access Message: The website cannot be found" Page.

I am new to `generatedata` project, please explain what I am missing and how could i install it.

Thanks for help !! in advance

Comment: what you get when you hit `http://localhost/generatedata-3.2.0/` ?

Comment: Thank U so much Yiiframe.... it was simple mistake i was doing
I was simply clicking on that folder, now my problem is solved, and i installed that software.

Sometimes it happens when you are doing so and so much try on a single thing to complete it on deadline.  :)